# Javascript delays

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I am making a test page full of buttons that execute different scripts. I want to change the background color every sec for 5 secs, 5 colors in total. I've read and watched videos on `setInterval` and `setTimeout` and I just don't get it.

What I want:

```
x
wait 1sec   
y
wait 1sec  
z
wait 1 sec
etc...
```

I wanted to do this all in one function, but I gave up on that due to seemingly needing to reference a function in the `setTimeout(function, 500)`

So I created a new function for each color change as you can see and then created a `disco()` which could call each background change.

Bit confused to be honest, the code should clarify what I tried. Suffice to say it doesn't work, this is where I gave up.

I would be very grateful for an explanation how to do this. Thanks!

```
function disco() {
    setTimeout(aquaman, 500);
    setTimeout(pinkman, 500);
    setTimeout(blueman, 500);
    setTimeout(redman, 500);
    setTimeout(brownman, 500);
}

function aquaman() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
}

function brownman() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
}

function redman() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function pinkman() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
}

function blueman() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Comment: How well do you know arrays?

Comment: `setTimeout` does not pause the script. It schedules the code to run later. This means all your `setTimeout` callbacks are scheduled to run at the same time.

Comment: arrays..I know bascially what they are - a data set, I don't really understand how it applies to this but I can see there is an array set in the example in the answer below..Ill look into it but it will take time for me to break it down. The fact you say that they are all set to execute at the same time does actually make sense thanks.. I tried the exact code above again using 500, 1000, 1500, 2000 and 2500 instead of 500 each time and it worked perfectly! Progress, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will change the color of the background to the next one in the array, all you need to do is set an interval on it to the time you want the color to change, drop a comment if you have doubts on how it works:

```js
    function changeColor(){
       var colors = ['aqua','brown','red','pink','blue'],
           currColor = ( ( colors.indexOf( document.body.style.backgroundColor ) + 1 ) % 5 );
       
       if(currColor === -1) currColor = 0;

       document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[ currColor ];
    }

    setInterval(changeColor, 1000)
```

Comment: @abforce has a cleaner solution tough.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var bg = {
        colors: ['red','blue', 'green'],
        next: 0,
        getNextColor: function(){
            return this.colors[this.next++ % this.colors.length];
        }
    };

    setInterval(function () {
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = bg.getNextColor();
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

[setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) is an asynchronous API. You use it to call have the browser execute the function you passed after n milliseconds. All of your setTimeout() calls has the timeout set to 500, which means that all of those functions will execute at roughly the same time.

This:

```
function disco()
{
setTimeout(aquaman, 500);
setTimeout(pinkman, 1000);
setTimeout(blueman, 1500);
setTimeout(redman, 2000);
setTimeout(brownman, 2500);
}
```

Will achieve the desired result, but consider writing this function to be more programmatic as part of your refactoring:

```
function aquaman() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
}

function brownman() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
}

function redman() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function pinkman() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
}

function blueman() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

function disco() {
    var timeout = 500;
    var funcs = [aquaman, brownman, redman, pinkman, blueman];
    funcs.forEach(function(func) {
      setTimeout(func, timeout);
      timeout += 500;
    });
}
```

This example reduces some duplication, but not all. We can still factor out those unnecessary, repeated function definitions:

```
function disco() {
    var timeout = 500;
    var colors = ['aqua', 'brown', 'red', 'pink', 'blue'];
    colors.forEach(function(color) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
      }, timeout);
      timeout += 500;
    });
}
```

Which is a perfectly serviceable solution to your problem.

Comment: @Kriggs There is no need for the <br> tags at all. The OP has them in the original sample.

Comment: sorry, it was my first post and I was just trying to lay it out better, there shouldnt be any <br>'s, my bad.

Comment: this one is very interesting thanks."colors.forEach(function(color) {" ..this line is pretty hard for me to understand but I like it! Theres some use of variables and brackets in that line that I didn't yet learn but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var colors = ['red','pink','blue'];
    var currentColor = 0;
    function changeColor() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if(currentColor === colors.length) {
           currentColor = 0;
        }
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[currentColor];
        changeColor(currentColor++);
      }, 500);
    }
    changeColor();
```

recursivly execute the changeColor in setTimeout, because you want to delay each execution 500ms

Comment: Code without any explanation isn't really that helpful.

Comment: sorry, I just thought the code is simple enough to explan itself

Answer (score -1):

Very Basic:

```
<script>

(function disco() {
   setTimeout(function aquaman() {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "aqua";}, 0);
    setTimeout(function pinkman() {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";}, 1000);
    setTimeout(function blueman() {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";}, 2000);
    setTimeout(function redman() {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";}, 3000);
    setTimeout(function brownman() { document.body.style.backgroundColor = "brown";}, 4000);
})();
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/qumagozosi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: yes I can see that your example makes me able to set intervals without defining a function seperately first and make disco an independent function. Thanks. The blue "function" in setTimeout(function had confused me throughout, I now see what that means, in this case it doesn't reference a function, its creating the function, I had been looking at examples at getting confused why the word function was there, but I see it now.

Comment: i notice you started this function with a ( and also have )(); at the very end, I dont understand what these are for, but without them it does work and is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: but to make this repeatable, I think I will have to use one of the more refined/advanced methods above such as incrementing the timeout. Being as the time delays are fixed, repeating them is not going to work - in the same way that my initial program didn't work because I had every event firing at the same time. I would imagine some of the examples above are repeatable, many thanks for all the info.

Comment: it would better fror me to be able to do it though between commands without setting each colorchange as a function at all. The functions are being created within disco, only to satisfy the need of setTimeout to reference a function.